# Identity Server and OIDC support for client-hosted login interface

Tags: angularjs, authentication, identityserver3, openid-connect

I have been reading a lot of different stackoverflow posts, the OAuth2 and OIDC specs, and the IdentityServer documentation. I'm still not sure of the definitive answer to this question. Do the underlying specs and IdentityServer itself support a scenario in which the Relying Party (or client application) hosts its own login UI and then calls IdentityServer with the credentials to authenticate the user? The specific scenario in which I'm interested is an AngularJS SPA using what I understand is the recommended Implicit flow. In that scenario, can the SPA host its own login UI and then authenticate the user through an IdentityServer-based authentication service? Is this supported? Is it recommended?

Comment: Or alternatively, is there a recommended approach for how the IdentityServer-hosted login UI integrates into an AngularJS SPA interface - something other than the popup that oidc-client.js supports?

Comment: did you found how to do it, ? thanks a lot